# MicroStrategy: Creating a table from multiple count(metrics) from different datasets

Tags: document, microstrategy, freeform

I'm trying to create a MicroStrategy document that has data from four freeform SQL reports. All of the freeform SQL reports would have the following format.

| Status | count(case) |
| --- | --- |
| Pass | 40 |
| Fail1 | 50 |
| Fail2 | 60 |

Now, I'm trying to create a document with the these four reports and trying to have a table of all the four reports combined. Something like this..

| Dataset | Status | count(case) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Pass | 40 |
| Two | Fail1 | 50 |
| Three | Fail3 | 70 |

Any idea how to achieve this only with the reports and the attribute (Status), metric from each report - count(case)

Comment: Why are you using FFSQL report ? And if you are using try to build a FFSQL report combining all the SQLs using UNION ALL.